# Cделать расширение, чтобы оно получало с сайта z-index и выводило его

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, z-index

Надо выпендриться перед подругой))
Знаю, что вас замучили подобные вопросы, но всё равно прошу помочь не сведущему, есть код. Мне необходимо сделать расширение, чтобы оно получало с сайта z-index и выводило его:

```js
var zndx = document.querySelector('[data-id="12"]').style.zIndex

document.write(zndx)
```

```html
<button data-id="32" aria-label="summer" style="z-index: 16, top:700">
```

не работает, помогите советом, пожалуйста, без jquery

Comment: Во-первых потому что `'[data-id="32"]'`, а не `'[data-id="12"]'`, во-вторых после `z-index: 16` должна быть `;`.

Answer (score 2):

После `z-index: 16` должна быть `;`, так же Вы пытаетесь получить элемент с `[data-id="12"]`, а не `[data-id="32"]`.

Рабочий код:

```js
const zndx = document.querySelector('[data-id="32"]').style.zIndex

console.log(zndx)
```

```html
<button data-id="32" aria-label="summer" style="z-index: 16; top:700">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const zndx = window.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('[data-id="32"]'),null).getPropertyValue("z-index");
console.log(zndx);
```

Comment: Вариант от @Simon работает только, если стили прописаны в html. Этот вариант будет работать в обоих случаях.

Comment: Спасибо, большое))
А если там таких строчек много, но только с разными цифрами, а мне надо конкретный по data-id получать, куда указывать значение?

Comment: Исправил, теперь так же само обращается.